# Проверка введённых данных

Tags: c#

Только начинаю изучать Шарп. В ходе выполнения задания задался вопросом:
Как сделать, чтобы проходила проверка введённых данных?
Например, если бы вводились данные типа string , то выводило бы текст, что не верно введены данные
И чтобы выводился этот текст до бесконечности пока не введут данные в верном формате. (Я так понял это делается через бесконечный цикл, а как остальное делается не могу ,,допереть,,)

---

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<int>();
            for(int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"Введите {i} число: ");
                list.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
            }

            foreach(var item in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Число = {item}");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

---

Comment: `while(true){ Console.Write("Число: "); if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int val){ break; } else{ Console.WriteLine("Не является числом!"); } }`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ так может ответом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё просто: используйте бесконечный `while` цикл (пример с парсингом числа):

```cs
int num;

Console.Write("Write number: ");

while (true)
{
    var input = Console.ReadLine();

    if (int.TryParse(input, out num))
        break; // обработка при успехе (почти всегда `break`)
    else // обработка при ошибке
    {
        // можно вывод по-красивше сделать – как вашей душе угодно
        Console.WriteLine("[ERROR]: Invalid input");
        Console.Write("Retry write number: ");
    }
}

Console.WriteLine($"Success! You've written: '{num}'"); // 'You've' пожно заменить на `You have`
```

<sub>Консоль</sub>

```
Write number: abc
[ERROR]: Invalid input
Retry write number: 123
Success! You've written: '123'
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @ivn Забыл сказать – вы "спасибо" говорите нажатием на "галочку", так что можете не писать отдельный комментарий для этого. Вот ссылка на [обсуждение](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction), где на enSO добавили кнопку "Спасибо".